# UIPickerView Random Spin UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, uipickerview, ibaction, arc4random

I have my `UIPickerWheel` setup to spin by a flick and populate a `UILabel` with whatever word value it lands on and that works just fine.

This issue that I'm having is when I added a button that spins my picker wheel and randomly chooses a word value. It spins the wheel just fine, and it populates my `UILabel` as well, but the `UILabel` and what is showing on the picker wheel doesn't match. I'm going to paste the code below.

I know that the way I have it setup right now is basically saying when user presses the button, spin the wheel and select a random value, and set the Text to label for the `selectedItem`. Right now the `selectedItem = ?` is where I'm having the issue. if I enter a string (e.g. @"hello")  the label will say "hello" no matter what is lands on and if I type a number value of 0-5610 (the words on my array) then it will show that word.

Right now I have it just randomly choose a word. So I know that issue is on that line.

The line where im assuming my issue is coming from would be:

```
 selectedItem =
```

/// HERE'S THE CODE///

```
 - (IBAction)spin:(id)sender {

[pickerView selectRow:(arc4random() % [self pickerView:pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:0]) inComponent:0  animated:YES];

selectedItem = [words objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [words count])];

[label setText:selectedItem];     

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two different random numbers. You set the picker with one and choose a word from the word list with the other. Instead, create one random number. Use it for both operations:

```
- (IBAction)spin:(id)sender {
    NSUInteger number = arc4random_uniform(words.count);
    [pickerView selectRow:number inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    selectedItem = words[number];
    label.text = selectedItem;     
}
```

This assumes the words in the picker match the words in the `words` array.

Comment: dang it Maddy, you are too quick!  And nice answer.

Comment: Thanks Maddy!! goes to show you how tired I am. I actually did it that way before and i kept getting an error, but i realized what i did wrong thanks to your answer. I really appreciate the quick response. worked like a charm! LMAO, i forgot to add the _uniform when i did it.